# How to replace a number with missing values all over the dataset?

Tags: r, function, for-loop, if-statement

I have written a user defined function that should get a dataset and some number of symbol, scan the entire dataset and replace all instances of this number with missing values. The code worked just fine until I put it in a user defined function (the loop and condition worked). I can't figure out why it's not working now. There are no warnings or errors, it just doesn't work. In addition, I wanted to ask if there is a way to choose which columns to do this operation on ?

My code is:

```
repMissing = function(ds,x)
{
  for(i in 1:nrow(ds))
  {
    for(j in 1:ncol(ds))
    {
      if (!is.na(ds[i,j]) && ds[i,j] == x)
      {
        ds[i,j] = NA
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I ran the following code:

```
repMissing(diet2,-99)
```

For some reason, the -99's are still not NA's.

Any advice will be most appreciated. Thank you !

Edit: This question is not identical to previous questions, since I am not only asking how to perform the task, but also what is wrong with my code, which is different from what was presented in previous questions.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace all occurences of -99 across the entire data frame can you just use:

```
df[ df == -99] <- NA
```

To integrate this back into a function:

```
repMissing <- function(df, x) { df[ df == as.integer(x)] <- NA }
```

Taking it a step further, you can even go as far as specifying which columns in a given data frame in which to perform the operation. See below some example code which replaces all occurrences of -99 from data frame `df` in only column 'a':

```
df[, colnames(df) %in% df('a')][df[, colnames(df) %in% c('a')] == -99] <- NA
```

Comment: Thank you Sam, I will certainly adopt your suggestion, but for general knowledge, why isn't my code working ? It was before I put it in a function....